# Julia: Apply 1 dimensional Julia function to multi-dimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia, idioms

I'm a "write Fortran in all languages" kind of person trying to learn modern programming practices. I have a one dimensional function `ft(lx)=HT(x,f(x),lx)`, where `x`, and `f(x)` are one dimensional arrays of size `nx`, and `lx` is the size of output array `ft`. I want to apply `HT` on a multidimensional array `f(x,y,z)`.

Basically I want to apply `HT` on all three dimensions to go from `f(x,y,z)` defined on `(nx,ny,nz)` dimensional grid, to `ft(lx,ly,lz)` defined on `(lx,ly,lz)` dimensional grid:

```
ft(lx,y,z)   = HT(x,f(x,y,z)   ,lx)
ft(lx,ly,z)  = HT(y,ft(lx,y,z) ,ly)
ft(lx,ly,lz) = HT(z,ft(lx,ly,z),lz)
```

In f95 style I would tend to write something like:

```
FTx=zeros((lx,ny,nz))
for k=1:nz
for j=1:ny
    FTx[:,j,k]=HT(x,f[:,j,k],lx)
end
end

FTxy=zeros((lx,ly,nz))
for k=1:nz
for i=1:lx
    FTxy[i,:,k]=HT(y,FTx[i,:,k],ly)
end
end

FTxyz=zeros((lx,ly,lz))
for j=1:ly
for i=1:lx
    FTxyz[i,j,:]=HT(z,FTxy[i,j,:],lz)
end
end
```

I know idiomatic Julia would require using something like `mapslices`. I was not able to understand how to go about doing this from the `mapslices` documentation.

So my question is: what would be the idiomatic Julia code, along with proper type declarations, equivalent to the Fortran style version?

A follow up sub-question would be: Is it possible to write a function

```
FT = HTnD((Tuple of x,y,z etc.),f(x,y,z), (Tuple of lx,ly,lz etc.))
```

that works with arbitrary dimensions? I.e. it would automatically adjust computation for 1,2,3 dimensions based on the sizes of input tuples and function?

Comment: To address your last question, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/cartesian/ and the link in the first paragraph therein.

Comment: I've got a piece of code [here](https://github.com/ettersi/ApproxTools.jl/blob/master/src/tucker.jl) which essentially does what you want.

Comment: @FredrikBagge Thanks, I will read the cartesian documentation and the multi-dimensional algorithm page.

Comment: @gTcV Thanks, but I am completely new to Julia and was not able to understand much of that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a piece of code [here](https://github.com/ettersi/ApproxTools.jl/blob/master/src/tucker.jl) which is fairly close to what you want. The key tool is [`Base.Cartesian.@nexprs`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/cartesian/#Anonymous-function-expressions-as-macro-arguments-1) which you can read up on in the linked documentation.

The three essential lines in my code are Lines 30 to 32. Here is a verbal description of what they do.

- Line 30: reshape an `n1 x n2 x ... nN`-sized array `C_{k-1}` into an `n1 x prod(n2,...,nN)` matrix `tmp_k`.
- Line 31: Apply the function `B[k]` to each column of `tmp_k`. In my code, there are some indirections here since I want to allow for `B[k]` to be a matrix or a function, but the basic idea is as described above. This is the part where you would want to bring in your `HT` function.
- Line 32: Reshape `tmp_k` back into an `N`-dimensional array and circularly permute the dimensions such that the second dimension of `tmp_k` ends up as the first dimension of `C_k`. This makes sure that the next iteration of the "loop" implied by `@nexprs` operates on the second dimension of the original array, and so on.

As you can see, my code avoids forming slices along arbitrary dimensions by permuting such that we only ever need to slice along the first dimension. This makes programming much easier, and it can also have some performance benefits. For example, computing the matrix-vector products `B * C[i1,:,i3]` for all `i1`,`i3`can be done easily and very efficiently by moving the second dimension of `C` into the first position of `tmp` and using `gemm` to compute `B * tmp`. Doing the same efficiently without the permutation would be much harder.

Comment: I really like the `tucker` function by @gTcV.
It has lots of fine tuning in it, particularly the rotation of dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @gTcV! The syntax makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Following @gTcV's code, your function would look like:

```
using Base.Cartesian

ht(x,F,d) = mapslices(f -> HT(x, f, d), F, dims = 1)

@generated function HTnD(
    xx::NTuple{N,Any},
    F::AbstractArray{<:Any,N},
    newdims::NTuple{N,Int}
) where {N}
    quote
        F_0 = F
        Base.Cartesian.@nexprs $N k->begin
            tmp_k = reshape(F_{k-1},(size(F_{k-1},1),prod(Base.tail(size(F_{k-1})))))
            tmp_k = ht(xx[k], tmp_k, newdims[k])
            F_k = Array(reshape(permutedims(tmp_k),(Base.tail(size(F_{k-1}))...,size(tmp_k,1))))
            # https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/30988
        end
        return $(Symbol("F_",N))
    end
end
```

A simpler version, which shows the usage of mapslices would look like this

```
function simpleHTnD(
    xx::NTuple{N,Any},
    F::AbstractArray{<:Any,N},
    newdims::NTuple{N,Int}
) where {N}
    for k = 1:N
        F = mapslices(f -> HT(xx[k], f, newdims[k]), F, dims = k)
    end
    return F
end
```

you could even use `foldl` if you are a friend of one-liners ;-)

```
fold_HTnD(xx, F, newdims) = foldl((F, k) -> mapslices(f -> HT(xx[k], f, newdims[k]), F, dims = k), 1:length(xx), init = F)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this function @HHFox.